# php check file name exist, rename the file

Tags: php, file-exists

How do I check if file name exists, rename the file?

for example, I upload a image `1086_002.jpg` if the file exists, rename the file as `1086_0021.jpg` and save, if `1086_0021.jpg` is exist, rename `1086_00211.jpg` and save , if `1086_00211.jpg` is exist, rename `1086_002111.jpg` and save...

Here is my code, it only can do if `1086_002.jpg` exist, rename the file as `1086_0021.jpg`, maybe should do a foreach, but how?

```
//$fullpath = 'images/1086_002.jpg';

if(file_exists($fullpath)) {
    $newpieces = explode(".", $fullpath);
    $frontpath = str_replace('.'.end($newpieces),'',$fullpath);
    $newpath = $frontpath.'1.'.end($newpieces);
}

file_put_contents($newpath, file_get_contents($_POST['upload']));
```

Comment: php file uploads do NOT go through $_POST. They go through $_FILES and have very different handling semantics than any other form fields.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$fullpath = 'images/1086_002.jpg';
$additional = '1';

while (file_exists($fullpath)) {
    $info = pathinfo($fullpath);
    $fullpath = $info['dirname'] . '/'
              . $info['filename'] . $additional
              . '.' . $info['extension'];
}
```

Comment: +1, I was intending to write something similar, but this is about as good as it can get.

Comment: @Baba how do you arrive at that conclusion? `$fullpath` is updated within the while loop (note the added `$additional` each time). The only way for an infinite loop here would be an infinite number of files.

Comment: You are suppose to always increase $additional ??? eg. `$additional++` ... since `$additional` is just `1` and it does not change .. the script would `run till it times out`  Thanks

Comment: `$additional` is appended *each time*, not incremented. Per the OP's request. Did you even try [running the code](http://codepad.org/KNuKds5d)?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just append a timestamp onto the filename?  Then you won't have to worry about arbitrarily long filenames for files which have been uploaded many times.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

```
$fullPath = "images/1086_002.jpg" ;
$fileInfo = pathinfo($fullPath);
list($prifix, $surfix) = explode("_",$fileInfo['filename']);
$x = intval($surfix);
$newFile = $fileInfo['dirname'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $prifix. "_" . str_pad($x, 2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)  . $fileInfo['extension'];
while(file_exists($newFile)) {
    $x++;
    $newFile = $fileInfo['dirname'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $prifix. "_" . str_pad($x, 2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)  . $fileInfo['extension'];
}

file_put_contents($newFile, file_get_contents($_POST['upload']));
```

I hope this Helps

Thanks

:)

Answer (score 1):

I feel this would be better. It will help keep track of how many times a file with the same name was uploaded. It works in the same way like Windows OS renames files if it finds one with the same name.

How it works: If the **media** directory has a file named **002.jpg** and you try to upload a file with the same name, it will be saved as **002(1).jpg** Another attempt to upload the same file will save the new file as **002(2).jpg**

Hope it helps.

```
$uploaded_filename_with_ext = $_FILES['uploaded_image']['name'];
$fullpath = 'media/' . $uploaded_filename_with_ext;
$file_info = pathinfo($fullpath);
$uploaded_filename = $file_info['filename'];

$count = 1;                 
while (file_exists($fullpath)) {
  $info = pathinfo($fullpath);
  $fullpath = $info['dirname'] . '/' . $uploaded_filename
  . '(' . $count++ . ')'
  . '.' . $info['extension'];
}
$image->save($fullpath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `if` statement to a `while` loop:

```
$newpath = $fullpath;
while(file_exists($newpath)) {
    $newpieces = explode(".", $fullpath);
    $frontpath = str_replace('.'.end($newpieces),'',$fullpath);
    $newpath = $frontpath.'1.'.end($newpieces);
}

file_put_contents($newpath, file_get_contents($_POST['upload']));
```

Comment: I just used what the OP provided.