# PHP Rename file if exists

Tags: php, file, if-statement, rename, exists

I've been working with image uploading and am wondering why this isn't working correctly? It doesn't move/upload the file with the new name if it already exists.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
     $filename=  $_FILES["imgfile"]["name"];
        if ((($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/gif")|| ($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/png")  || ($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) && ($_FILES["imgfile"]["size"] < 20000000)){
    $loc = "userpics/$filename";
    if(file_exists($loc)){
        $increment = 0;
        list($name, $ext) = explode('.', $loc);
        while(file_exists($loc)) {
            $increment++;
            $loc = $name. $increment . '.' . $ext;
            $filename = $name. $increment . '.' . $ext;
        }
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgfile"]["tmp_name"],"userpics/$loc");

    }
    else{
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgfile"]["tmp_name"],"userpics/$filename");

    }
     }
     else{
    echo "invalid file.";
     }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `while`, you should do an `if(file_exists){...}`

Comment: Maybe you should check the returned value from `move_uploaded_file`?  It looks like if the file exists, you end up moving it to `userpics/userprics/blahblah`

Comment: @Fred-ii-: That will only rename the file once, it won't check if the renamed file exists.

Comment: @TheBlueDog Good point; I stand corrected.

Comment: You should check the file name extension, otherwise one can upload a `.php` file or some other malicious file.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: No worries fella, I'll keep you right... ;)

Comment: @TheBlueDog hahaha, no problemo ;-)

Comment: @TheBlueDog It seems like my comment should have been rephrased as "**add** an `if`" OP just accepted an answer below with the conditional statement at the beginning. I guess I was *partially* right ;-) Loops aren't my strong points.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: It's the same code, Mr Llama was just pointing out that `userpics` was added to the path twice.

Comment: @TheBlueDog *Ah yes*, I see the repositioning now. *"Old age".*

Comment: @Fred-ii-: More coffee? :D

Comment: @TheBlueDog Yes please, and with a shot of Espresso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've included the folder path in `$loc`, then you attempt to move a file to `userpics/$loc`, which is probably incorrect.  See the comments:

```
$filename = "example.jpg";
$loc = "userpics/$filename";
if(file_exists($loc)){
    $increment = 0;
    list($name, $ext) = explode('.', $loc);
    while(file_exists($loc)) {
        $increment++;
        // $loc is now "userpics/example1.jpg"
        $loc = $name. $increment . '.' . $ext;
        $filename = $name. $increment . '.' . $ext;
    }

    // Now you're trying to move the uploaded file to "userpics/$loc"
    //   which expands to "userpics/userpics/example1.jpg"
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgfile"]["tmp_name"],"userpics/$loc");
} else {
    // ...
```

As a general debugging tip, *always* check a function's return value to see if it was successful.  Secondly, display the function's input values if it's failing.  It will make debugging things a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$fullpath = 'images/1086_002.jpg';
$additional = '1';

while (file_exists($fullpath)) {
    $info = pathinfo($fullpath);
    $fullpath = $info['dirname'] . '/'
              . $info['filename'] . $additional
              . '.' . $info['extension'];
}
```

Thanks to here:[Clickie!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015232/php-check-file-name-exist-rename-the-file)