# How to rename a photo then upload it to server. so not be identical

Tags: php, android

I want to upload images to the server but how to rename them so they not be identical ?

in the server its saved `image_upload.jpg`
in this php code I rename the file

```
  $base=$_POST['image'];
     $binary=base64_decode($base);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    $file = fopen('uploaded_images.jpg', 'wb'); // here I am naming it
```

I am thinking in java to add the time upload it in milliseconds ... like `image_upload3123.jpg` with this

```
  Calendar thisCal = Calendar.getInstance();
  thisCal.getTimeInMillis();
```

then send the value send it to server .. is this good way? or there is better way?

Comment: Not everyone may have JAVA enabled on their end (unless you meant Javascript; those are two different animals altogether, which still applies). Best to use a PHP/serverside method and there are plenty of examples out there.

Comment: @Fred-ii- what you mean 'Not everyone may have JAVA enabled on their end.` can you explain please. and please can you point out for an example ?

Comment: I made an edit to my comment; reload it.

Comment: fastest solution is to add the current time to the file name with time() command

Comment: $file = fopen('uploaded_images'.time().'.jpg', 'wb'); // here I am naming it

Comment: @Fred-ii- I meant java as for android.

Comment: Add current Time stamp as daniel said. If you want identify each image use any unique id and associate it with timestamp

Comment: @DanielMendel time() is in seconds ? can I make it in milliseconds ?  I am afraid to have identical naming

Comment: then that would only be good of people using Android to upload with, and/or Java enabled on their system. I for one, don't have Java enabled on my PC, just saying. Again, use a serverside method.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ill go for server side

Comment: @I-Kod how to set a unique id ? is there a fuction in php for that ?

Comment: @Moudiz, The correct solution is to always check if the file doesn't exist before, since if you are going to name something randomly there is always a slight chance of it already existing , you can use various encrpytions such as md5 to generate a unique string but you will need some unqie ids to begin with

Comment: I found a duplicate question for exactly what you need. See the accepted answer for it. @Moudiz

Comment: @DanielMendel md5 will always have the same hash for the same file name.

Comment: @Fred -ii, you are correct that's why I added the requirement of having a unique id to begin with

Comment: Yes there is function called uniqid() @Moudiz

Comment: @DanielMendel That was just a sidenote about MD5. But what you said about using unique id's would be the method to use for sure. *Cheers*

Comment: @DanielMendel Intersting ... please can you tell me how to do a check if image exists ? a simple example would be great ... Fred -ii thanks ill check the asnwer

Comment: You're welcome @Moudiz *Cheers*

Comment: To hit two posts with one stone, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015232/php-check-file-name-exist-rename-the-file which would also be another duplicate. The duplicate it was closed with, was based on your original post. Therefore a reopen would only apply if you edited your question with your "new" requirement that was suggested by someone other than yourself. @Moudiz You could have Google'd this.

Comment: @I-Kod, nice I didn't know it exists, makes it much more easy, Moudiz that is what you will want to use, Also based on the documentation it is suggested to md5 the uniqid value to get a more random file name to prevent hacking

Comment: your really helped me guys thank you `Ikod` `Fred` and `Daniel` ill check all the info you have provided

Comment: here is a new requirement suggested by someone else. Delete the question

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did try [google](http://www.google.com.lb/search?hl=en-LB&source=hp&biw=&bih=&q=android+rename+a+photo+after+uploading&gbv=2&oq=android+rename+a+photo+after+uploading&gs_l=heirloom-hp.3..0l10.270295.278455.0.278671.38.21.0.0.0.0.1956.3505.2j0j2j0j2j8-1.7.0....0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-hp..34.4.2717.KiPbtkeEhBk) ... Drew still need 4 to close , however comments contain useful info for people like me who new to php

Comment: @Moudiz Try out something from the links that I have provided to you. If you have a hard time with something, edit your question with your new code. The question could then be voted to reopen. However, a fair amount of effort on your part is required. You will succeed ;-) Just put your mind to it. Use error reporting also to check for errors.